# How to get the azure web app url https ssl certificate expiry date?

Tags: c#, azure

I am able to get ssl certificate expiry date using http web request c# for Google.com but unable to get the ssl certificate expiry date for my web application hosted in azure

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://sitename.azurewebsites.us");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
 X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
 X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
string cedate = cert2.GetExpirationDateString();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! You should include code in your question to show what you have tried so far, so we can help point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the ssl certificate details, you could use `X509Certificate2UI` to retrieve the certificate. You could try with the below code.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://sitename.azurewebsites.net");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
            //retrieve the ssl cert and assign it to an X509Certificate object
            X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

            //convert the X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2 object by passing it into the constructor
            X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

            //show expiratin date
            Console.WriteLine("expiratin date: "+cert2.GetExpirationDateString());
```

[image]

Comment: @dinesh kumar , my site is a sitename.azurewebsite.net, what did you get from cert2 object or did you get any error? Or maybe you could share your site url.

Comment: @dinesh kumar, please check this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur2yn.png),  I could get the date.

Comment: @dinesh kumar, i test the second url it also could be retrieved.  Could your share what you get?

Comment: Unable to read data from transport connection. An existing connection is forcibly closed by remote host. From the url  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Comment: So your problem isn't  couldn't get the certificate but the host connection.

Comment: @dinesh kumar,maybe you could refer to this answer firstly to solve your exception.https://stackoverflow.com/a/21447045/10383250

Comment: it is working now after adding the lines before web request, ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                       SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Glad you could solve it, if my answer could help you, you could accept it as the answer.